# Identifying changes in large amounts of data using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, bigdata, data-mining, amazon-emr

I have a very large amount of data (about a billion rows) of a `DATE` column and a `RESULT` column.
The values in the `RESULT` column are predominantly the name but every now and then there would be a significant deviation in the value. I want to only identify the dates where there was a large deviation.
So from an input dataframe as such:

```
+----------+------+
|      DATE|RESULT|
+----------+------+
|2020-06-24|   4.2|
|2020-05-17|   4.5|
|2020-05-11|   4.5|
|2020-07-30|   4.2|
|2020-07-30|   4.2|
|2020-06-29|   4.2|
|2020-06-29|   4.2|
|2020-03-04|   4.5|
|2020-06-01|   4.2|
|2020-06-27|   4.2|
|2020-06-29|   4.2|
|2020-06-29|   4.2|
|2020-04-17|   4.5|
|2020-04-17|   4.5|
|2020-01-04|   4.5|
|2020-02-29|   4.5|
|2020-07-07|   4.2|
|2020-05-07|   4.5|
|2020-06-09|   4.2|
|2020-06-22|   4.2|
+----------+------+
```

I would expect an output of:

```
+----------+------+
|      DATE|RESULT|
+----------+------+
|2020-05-11|   4.5|
|2020-07-30|   4.2|
|2020-06-29|   4.2|
|2020-04-17|   4.5|
|2020-02-29|   4.5|
|2020-07-07|   4.2|
|2020-05-07|   4.5|
|2020-06-09|   4.2|
+----------+------+
```

I tried using the window and lag functions, but it is forcing the entire dataset into a single node, and therefore loses the advantage of using distributed computing.
I came across a suggestion in StackOverflow to use the Median and Mean Absolute Deviation (MAD) and defining a threshold to identify the records with abnormal shifts, but I could not find a MAD statistic function in the pyspark.sql.functions library.
Does anyone have any better ideas? I would greatly appreciate it.
I am coding in pyspark, but if the solution is in spark/scala that's fine too.
Thank You

Comment: You want to compare and calculate the shift between the current and the previous, how the deviation can let you know the big shift? Your aim and what you are trying are not matched in my opinion. The deviation is used to catch the anomaly data which has the value most differ from the median or mean, not shifting from the previous and current.

Comment: Whatever you want, you first have to calculate the shifting value by using `lag` and I don't think there is another way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I agree that using `lag` would be the most rigorous way, but I was thinking of using the median and MAD to define a threshold and flag any record where the value crosses the threshold. That way I can find out which records have a significant shift. I don't think using window is an option for my very large dataset

Comment: I mean MAD is not suitable for your goal, that is totally different concept but you did not understand. MAD is only for the current row, it is not giving any info on how much shift. It is for how far from the median or means.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. If I use MAD, I can find out if a row has a significant shift from the median, but it wont tell me what the value of the previous row is. Hmmm
Is there a way to use `lag` without using `window`?

Comment: That is correct. But I think the window is not a matter but the lag needs the ordering in the window that is the problem. I have no idea about that :( sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this link useful for calculation of MAD https://www.advancinganalytics.co.uk/blog/2020/9/2/identifying-outliers-in-spark-30

Adding relevant content from that link below:

MAD=Median(|xi-xm|)

where xm is median of the data set and xi is value in data set.
MAD is median of the difference between each value and median of the entire dataset

consider a df with columns 'category', 'data_col'

‘percentile()’ expects a column and an array of percentiles to calculate (for median we can provide ‘array(0.5)’ as 50% value is median) and will return an array of results.

```py
MADdf = df.groupby('category')\
.agg(F.expr('percentile(data_col, array(0.5))')[0]\
.alias('data_col_median'))\
.join(df, "category", "left")\
.withColumn("data_col_difference_median", F.abs(F.col('data_col')-F.col('data_col_median')))\
    .groupby('category', 'data_col_median')\
    .agg(F.expr('percentile(data_col_difference_median, array(0.5))')[0]\
    .alias('median_absolute_difference'))
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is a poor quality answer. You should provide the answer here rather than link to it. Because if some guy in the future finds this question, when he follows the link, the information may no longer be there.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Added relevant content from the link to answer section